# How to access the data type of the each column of a table in Matlab

Tags: string, matlab, types, cell

I have a table which contains categorical and numerical data. In order to separate those two, I want to know how to access the data type of the each column of a table.

Since I don't know how to, I tried function iscellstr as follows:

```
for i=1:size(adjusted_dataset,2)
    if iscellstr(adjusted_dataset(:,i))
        adjusted_string = adjusted_dataset(:,i);
    else
        adjusted_numerical = adjusted_dataset(:,i);
    end
end
```

But it does not seem to be working either. Any help would be appreciated.

Summary of the table looks like this:

```
  >> summary(adjusted_dataset)

Variables:

rev_Mean: 100000x1 double
    Values:

        min       -6.1675   
        median     48.195   
        max        3843.3   
        NaNs          357   

mou_Mean: 100000x1 double
    Values:

        min           0     
        median    355.5     
        max       12207     
        NaNs        357     

totmrc_Mean: 100000x1 double
    Values:

        min       -26.915      
        median      44.99      
        max        409.99      
        NaNs          357      

da_Mean: 100000x1 double
    Values:

        min            0   
        median    0.2475   
        max       159.39   
        NaNs         357   

ovrmou_Mean: 100000x1 double
    Values:

        min            0       
        median      2.75       
        max       4320.8       
        NaNs         357       

ovrrev_Mean: 100000x1 double
    Values:

        min            0       
        median         1       
        max       1102.4       
        NaNs         357       

vceovr_Mean: 100000x1 double
    Values:

        min            0       
        median    0.6825       
        max       896.09       
        NaNs         357       

datovr_Mean: 100000x1 double
    Values:

        min            0       
        median         0       
        max       423.54       
        NaNs         357       

roam_Mean: 100000x1 double
    Values:

        min            0     
        median         0     
        max       3685.2     
        NaNs         357     

rev_Range: 100000x1 double
    Values:

        min           0      
        median    16.19      
        max       13741      
        NaNs        357      

mou_Range: 100000x1 double
    Values:

        min           0      
        median      244      
        max       43050      
        NaNs        357      

totmrc_Range: 100000x1 double
    Values:

        min            0        
        median         0        
        max       599.98        
        NaNs         357        

da_Range: 100000x1 double
    Values:

        min           0     
        median     0.99     
        max       77.22     
        NaNs        357     

ovrmou_Range: 100000x1 double
    Values:

        min          0          
        median      10          
        max       4292          
        NaNs       357          

ovrrev_Range: 100000x1 double
    Values:

        min            0        
        median      3.51        
        max       2410.1        
        NaNs         357        

vceovr_Range: 100000x1 double
    Values:

        min            0        
        median       2.4        
        max       2409.8        
        NaNs         357        

datovr_Range: 100000x1 double
    Values:

        min            0        
        median         0        
        max       838.89        
        NaNs         357        

roam_Range: 100000x1 double
    Values:

        min           0       
        median        0       
        max       13623       
        NaNs        357       

change_mou: 100000x1 double
    Values:

        min       -3875       
        median    -6.25       
        max       31219       
        NaNs        891       

change_rev: 100000x1 double
    Values:

        min       -1107.7     
        median     -0.315     
        max        9963.7     
        NaNs          891     

drop_vce_Mean: 100000x1 double
    Values:

        min            0         
        median         3         
        max       232.67         

drop_dat_Mean: 100000x1 double
    Values:

        min            0         
        median         0         
        max       207.33         

blck_vce_Mean: 100000x1 double
    Values:

        min            0         
        median         1         
        max       385.33         

blck_dat_Mean: 100000x1 double
    Values:

        min            0         
        median         0         
        max       413.33         

unan_vce_Mean: 100000x1 double
    Values:

        min            0         
        median        16         
        max       848.67         

unan_dat_Mean: 100000x1 double
    Values:

        min            0         
        median         0         
        max       81.667         

plcd_vce_Mean: 100000x1 double
    Values:

        min            0         
        median    100.33         
        max         2289         

plcd_dat_Mean: 100000x1 double
    Values:

        min            0         
        median         0         
        max       733.67         

recv_vce_Mean: 100000x1 double
    Values:

        min            0         
        median    26.667         
        max       3369.3         

recv_sms_Mean: 100000x1 double
    Values:

        min            0         
        median         0         
        max       517.33         

comp_vce_Mean: 100000x1 double
    Values:

        min            0         
        median    75.667         
        max       1894.3         

comp_dat_Mean: 100000x1 double
    Values:

        min            0         
        median         0         
        max       559.33         

custcare_Mean: 100000x1 double
    Values:

        min            0         
        median         0         
        max       675.33         

ccrndmou_Mean: 100000x1 double
    Values:

        min            0         
        median         0         
        max       861.33         

cc_mou_Mean: 100000x1 double
    Values:

        min            0       
        median         0       
        max       602.95       

inonemin_Mean: 100000x1 double
    Values:

        min            0         
        median    12.333         
        max       3086.7         

threeway_Mean: 100000x1 double
    Values:

        min        0             
        median     0             
        max       66             

mou_cvce_Mean: 100000x1 double
    Values:

        min            0         
        median     146.2         
        max       4514.5         

mou_cdat_Mean: 100000x1 double
    Values:

        min            0         
        median         0         
        max       3032.1         

mou_rvce_Mean: 100000x1 double
    Values:

        min            0         
        median      50.2         
        max       3287.2         

owylis_vce_Mean: 100000x1 double
    Values:

        min            0           
        median        13           
        max       644.33           

mouowylisv_Mean: 100000x1 double
    Values:

        min            0           
        median    11.977           
        max       1802.7           

iwylis_vce_Mean: 100000x1 double
    Values:

        min            0           
        median         2           
        max       519.33           

mouiwylisv_Mean: 100000x1 double
    Values:

        min            0           
        median      3.21           
        max       1703.5           

peak_vce_Mean: 100000x1 double
    Values:

        min            0         
        median    60.333         
        max       2090.7         

peak_dat_Mean: 100000x1 double
    Values:

        min         0            
        median      0            
        max       281            

mou_peav_Mean: 100000x1 double
    Values:

        min            0         
        median    115.37         
        max       4015.3         

mou_pead_Mean: 100000x1 double
    Values:

        min            0         
        median         0         
        max       1036.1         

opk_vce_Mean: 100000x1 double
    Values:

        min            0        
        median    34.333        
        max       1643.3        

opk_dat_Mean: 100000x1 double
    Values:

        min            0        
        median         0        
        max       309.67        

mou_opkv_Mean: 100000x1 double
    Values:

        min            0         
        median    75.842         
        max       4337.9         

mou_opkd_Mean: 100000x1 double
    Values:

        min          0           
        median       0           
        max       2922           

drop_blk_Mean: 100000x1 double
    Values:

        min            0         
        median    5.3333         
        max       489.67         

attempt_Mean: 100000x1 double
    Values:

        min          0          
        median     101          
        max       2289          

complete_Mean: 100000x1 double
    Values:

        min            0         
        median        76         
        max       1894.3         

callfwdv_Mean: 100000x1 double
    Values:

        min            0         
        median         0         
        max       81.333         

callwait_Mean: 100000x1 double
    Values:

        min             0        
        median    0.33333        
        max        212.67        

drop_vce_Range: 100000x1 double
    Values:

        min         0             
        median      3             
        max       313             

drop_dat_Range: 100000x1 double
    Values:

        min         0             
        median      0             
        max       143             

blck_vce_Range: 100000x1 double
    Values:

        min         0             
        median      1             
        max       739             

blck_dat_Range: 100000x1 double
    Values:

        min         0             
        median      0             
        max       680             

unan_vce_Range: 100000x1 double
    Values:

        min          0            
        median      11            
        max       1395            

unan_dat_Range: 100000x1 double
    Values:

        min         0             
        median      0             
        max       223             

plcd_vce_Range: 100000x1 double
    Values:

        min          0            
        median      43            
        max       2656            

plcd_dat_Range: 100000x1 double
    Values:

        min          0            
        median       0            
        max       1352            

recv_vce_Range: 100000x1 double
    Values:

        min          0            
        median      14            
        max       2109            

recv_sms_Range: 100000x1 double
    Values:

        min         0             
        median      0             
        max       244             

comp_vce_Range: 100000x1 double
    Values:

        min          0            
        median      32            
        max       1748            

comp_dat_Range: 100000x1 double
    Values:

        min          0            
        median       0            
        max       1274            

custcare_Range: 100000x1 double
    Values:

        min         0             
        median      0             
        max       690             

ccrndmou_Range: 100000x1 double
    Values:

        min          0            
        median       0            
        max       1590            

cc_mou_Range: 100000x1 double
    Values:

        min            0        
        median         0        
        max       1201.8        

inonemin_Range: 100000x1 double
    Values:

        min          0            
        median       8            
        max       1879            

threeway_Range: 100000x1 double
    Values:

        min        0              
        median     0              
        max       95              

mou_cvce_Range: 100000x1 double
    Values:

        min            0          
        median     78.07          
        max       5439.6          

mou_cdat_Range: 100000x1 double
    Values:

        min          0            
        median       0            
        max       3748            

mou_rvce_Range: 100000x1 double
    Values:

        min            0          
        median     34.73          
        max       7146.7          

owylis_vce_Range: 100000x1 double
    Values:

        min         0               
        median      8               
        max       699               

mouowylisv_Range: 100000x1 double
    Values:

        min            0            
        median      9.43            
        max       1897.2            

iwylis_vce_Range: 100000x1 double
    Values:

        min         0               
        median      2               
        max       441               

mouiwylisv_Range: 100000x1 double
    Values:

        min            0            
        median       4.4            
        max       2011.3            

peak_vce_Range: 100000x1 double
    Values:

        min          0            
        median      28            
        max       1291            

peak_dat_Range: 100000x1 double
    Values:

        min         0             
        median      0             
        max       350             

mou_peav_Range: 100000x1 double
    Values:

        min            0          
        median    64.855          
        max         4113          

mou_pead_Range: 100000x1 double
    Values:

        min            0          
        median         0          
        max       1851.8          

opk_vce_Range: 100000x1 double
    Values:

        min          0           
        median      19           
        max       1679           

opk_dat_Range: 100000x1 double
    Values:

        min         0            
        median      0            
        max       929            

mou_opkv_Range: 100000x1 double
    Values:

        min            0          
        median     52.97          
        max       4783.7          

mou_opkd_Range: 100000x1 double
    Values:

        min            0          
        median         0          
        max       2881.6          

drop_blk_Range: 100000x1 double
    Values:

        min         0             
        median      5             
        max       724             

attempt_Range: 100000x1 double
    Values:

        min          0           
        median      44           
        max       2669           

complete_Range: 100000x1 double
    Values:

        min          0            
        median      32            
        max       2028            

callfwdv_Range: 100000x1 double
    Values:

        min         0             
        median      0             
        max       102             

callwait_Range: 100000x1 double
    Values:

        min         0             
        median      0             
        max       227             

churn: 100000x1 categorical
    Values:

        0    50438  
        1    49562  

months: 100000x1 double
    Values:

        min        6      
        median    16      
        max       61      

uniqsubs: 100000x1 categorical
    Values:

        1      61966     
        2      27556     
        3       6579     
        4       2556     
        5        835     
        6        315     
        7        111     
        8         40     
        9         20     
        10         9     
        11         5     
        12         4     
        13         2     
        18         1     
        196        1     

actvsubs: 100000x1 categorical
    Values:

        0        81     
        1     70524     
        2     24422     
        3      3776     
        4       899     
        5       262     
        6        20     
        7         5     
        8         6     
        9         3     
        11        1     
        53        1     

new_cell: 100000x1 cell string

crclscod: 100000x1 cell string

asl_flag: 100000x1 cell string

totcalls: 100000x1 double
    Values:

        min           0     
        median     1822     
        max       98874     

totmou: 100000x1 double
    Values:

        min                0
        median        5191.5
        max       2.3342e+05

totrev: 100000x1 double
    Values:

        min         3.65  
        median    804.53  
        max        27322  

adjrev: 100000x1 double
    Values:

        min          2.4  
        median    737.76  
        max        27071  

adjmou: 100000x1 double
    Values:

        min                0
        median        5102.5
        max       2.3286e+05

adjqty: 100000x1 double
    Values:

        min           0   
        median     1789   
        max       98705   

avgrev: 100000x1 double
    Values:

        min         0.48  
        median     49.89  
        max       924.27  

avgmou: 100000x1 double
    Values:

        min            0  
        median    360.19  
        max       7040.1  

avgqty: 100000x1 double
    Values:

        min            0  
        median     127.5  
        max       3017.1  

avg3mou: 100000x1 double
    Values:

        min          0     
        median     358     
        max       7716     

avg3qty: 100000x1 double
    Values:

        min          0     
        median     125     
        max       3909     

avg3rev: 100000x1 double
    Values:

        min          1     
        median      48     
        max       1593     

avg6mou: 100000x1 double
    Values:

        min          0     
        median     363     
        max       7217     
        NaNs      2839     

avg6qty: 100000x1 double
    Values:

        min          0     
        median     127     
        max       3256     
        NaNs      2839     

avg6rev: 100000x1 double
    Values:

        min         -2     
        median      50     
        max        866     
        NaNs      2839     

prizm_social_one: 100000x1 cell string

csa: 100000x1 cell string

area: 100000x1 cell string

dualband: 100000x1 cell string

refurb_new: 100000x1 cell string

hnd_price: 100000x1 double
    Values:

        min         9.99     
        median     99.99     
        max       499.99     
        NaNs         847     

pre_hnd_price: 100000x1 double
    Values:

        min         9.99         
        median     59.99         
        max       499.99         
        NaNs       57515         

phones: 100000x1 double
    Values:

        min        1      
        median     1      
        max       28      
        NaNs       1      

last_swap: 100000x1 cell string

models: 100000x1 double
    Values:

        min        1      
        median     1      
        max       16      
        NaNs       1      

hnd_webcap: 100000x1 cell string

truck: 100000x1 categorical
    Values:

        0              79713  
        1              18555  
        <undefined>     1732  

mtrcycle: 100000x1 categorical
    Values:

        0              96867     
        1               1401     
        <undefined>     1732     

rv: 100000x1 categorical
    Values:

        0              90153
        1               8115
        <undefined>     1732

ownrent: 100000x1 cell string

lor: 100000x1 categorical
    Values:

        0               2193
        1              10016
        2               8985
        3               5849
        4               5409
        5               4928
        6               4485
        7               4269
        8               3632
        9               2979
        10              2330
        11              1982
        12              1703
        13              1651
        14              1222
        15              8177
        <undefined>    30190

dwlltype: 100000x1 cell string

marital: 100000x1 cell string

mailordr: 100000x1 cell string

age1: 100000x1 double
    Values:

        min          0  
        median      36  
        max         99  
        NaNs      1732  

age2: 100000x1 double
    Values:

        min          0  
        median       0  
        max         99  
        NaNs      1732  

mailresp: 100000x1 cell string

children: 100000x1 cell string

adults: 100000x1 double
    Values:

        min           1   
        median        2   
        max           6   
        NaNs      23019   

infobase: 100000x1 cell string

income: 100000x1 categorical
    Values:

        1               4033   
        2               2260   
        3               5830   
        4               7790   
        5               8277   
        6              18802   
        7              11597   
        8               5142   
        9              10833   
        <undefined>    25436   

numbcars: 100000x1 double
    Values:

        min           1     
        median        1     
        max           3     
        NaNs      49366     

cartype: 100000x1 cell string

HHstatin: 100000x1 cell string

dwllsize: 100000x1 cell string

forgntvl: 100000x1 categorical
    Values:

        0              92571     
        1               5697     
        <undefined>     1732     

ethnic: 100000x1 cell string

kid0_2: 100000x1 cell string

kid3_5: 100000x1 cell string

kid6_10: 100000x1 cell string

kid11_15: 100000x1 cell string

kid16_17: 100000x1 cell string

creditcd: 100000x1 cell string

car_buy: 100000x1 cell string

eqpdays: 100000x1 double
    Values:

        min         -5     
        median     342     
        max       1823     
        NaNs         1     

Customer_ID: 100000x1 double
    Values:

        min          1e+06     
        median    1.05e+06     
        max        1.1e+06
```

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood but are numerical/categorical data always in the same column or not necessarily?

Comment: No they are not. For example first column is numerical and every data in that column is numerical as well where second is numerical etc.

Comment: ok can you show a bit of what the table looks like? It might not be working because you are not indexing either adjusted_string or adjusted_numerical, hence the values are repeatedly overwritten through the loop.

Comment: @Benoit_11 I added my summary I hope it helps

Comment: alright I just posted an answer; hope this is what you want!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is some sample code that does what you are looking for. I modified a sample table from the Mathworks doc but you can apply the code to yours. Notice that in my example I don't have categorical data (I was a bit lazy sorry :P) but as you will see it does not change the code.

There is also a lot of information [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/access-data-in-a-table.html) about tables, their properties and how to access data in them.

```
clear all
clc

LastName = {'Smith';'Johnson';'Williams';'Jones';'Brown'};
Age = [38;43;38;40;49];
FirstName = {'Amanda' ;'Brenda';'Carl'; 'Denis'; 'Ethan'};
Weight = [176;163;131;133;119];
BloodPressure = [124 93; 109 77; 125 83; 117 75; 122 80];
FavoriteColor = {'blue' ;'red' ;'yellow'; 'orange' ;'colorblind' };

T = table(Age,FirstName,Weight,BloodPressure,FavoriteColor,...
    'RowNames',LastName)
```

The table looks like this:

```
T = 

                Age    FirstName    Weight    BloodPressure    FavoriteColor
                ___    _________    ______    _____________    _____________

    Smith       38     'Amanda'     176       124     93       'blue'       
    Johnson     43     'Brenda'     163       109     77       'red'        
    Williams    38     'Carl'       131       125     83       'yellow'     
    Jones       40     'Denis'      133       117     75       'orange'     
    Brown       49     'Ethan'      119       122     80       'colorblind' 

%// Initialize. Since we don't know the size beforehand, make the cell arrays
%//bigger ans afterwards remove empty cells.
CategoricalData = cell(size(T,2),1);
NumericData = cell(size(T,2),1);
StringcData = cell(size(T,2),1);

%// Check different conditions and append data to respective cell arrays.
for k = 1:size(T,2)

    CurrentData = T{:,k}; %// Access all rows of a given column.

    if iscategorical(CurrentData)

        CategoricalData{k} = CurrentData; 

    elseif iscellstr(CurrentData)

        StringcData{k} = CurrentData;

    else

         NumericData{k} = CurrentData;
    end
end

%// Remove empty cells
 CategoricalData(cellfun('isempty',CategoricalData)) = [];
 NumericData(cellfun('isempty',NumericData)) = [];
 StringcData(cellfun('isempty',StringcData)) = [];

%// Display results
CategoricalData
NumericData
StringcData
```

And the result:

```
CategoricalData = 

   Empty cell array: 0-by-1


NumericData = 

    [5x1 double]
    [5x1 double]
    [5x2 double]


StringcData = 

    {5x1 cell}
    {5x1 cell}
```

That's about it. Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you for the answer. After applying your code to my data, I get results as StringcData = {100000x1 cell} NumericData = [100000x1 double] etc. What I want is that finding the string data from the dataset and reserving these string columns in StringcData variable.

Comment: I mean I can learn how many categorical data columns I have from your code but I want the actual categorical data in those columns and reserve them in a different table.

Comment: sorry for the delay. I'm not sure to get it; you want to access the data in the cell arrays is that it? You can get the content in multiple ways, like A = StringcData{:} for instance.

Comment: By the way, A = StringcData{:} only works for if there is a single column of string data and when I try to use Str= cell2mat(StringcData) function, I get "Cannot support cell arrays containing cell arrays or objects."

Comment: mhhh you might need to use cell2mat(StringcData{:}). Using : conctenates all the cells into a single big cell, so this should be ok.

Comment: @Ege how come did you unaccept the answer it does not work anymore?

Comment: I'm sorry it must have been an accident

Comment: ok no problem! I was wondering why it would not work actually that was an interesting question!